# How can I pass this concentration to ppm?

Tags: concentration

So the exercise gave us the concentration of a solution (1,5 x 10^-3 M) and the volume (10 mL).

The 1st part of the exercise was to calculate the amount of volume we need from a more concentrated solution (0,010 M). I calculated the volume which is 1,5 mL.

The solution is from CoCl2.6H2O.

Now they want us to pass the concentration of our prepared solution to ppm. How can I do that? Thanks!

Comment: You make a stated assumption that 1.5 milliliters of solution has a mass of 1.5 grams. For such a dilute solution the assumption is surely good to 2 significant figures. // You do understand what ppm is don't you?!?

Comment: I'm not making any assumption! ppm is mass of solute/mass of solution x 10^6... Now how can I calculate it?

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: BTW, I believe @MaxW didn't mean that you **made** an assumption, but rather that you **should make** one - since you want to solve your problem